# Embedding flash into a facebook iframe canvas

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to embed a flash file into my facebook iframe canvas, I am using the PHP sdk, here is my code,

```
echo "<fb:swf swfsrc=\"http://my.site.com/facebook-test/the_file.swf\" width=\"760\" height=\"710\" />";
```

I have tried everything but it still doesn't seem to want to display.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include the imgsrc property.  This is a thumbnail image that is displayed to begin with as facebook requires a user to click on the thumbnail before the actual swf is loaded

So you need something like:

```
echo "<fb:swf imgsrc=\"http://my.site.com/facebook-test/the_file_thumbnail.jpg\" swfsrc=\"http://my.site.com/facebook-test/the_file.swf\" width=\"760\" height=\"710\" />";
```

Comment: I have tried that and it still doesn't want to display, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure then.  Do you get anything at all?  If you use firebug or one of the other inspectors, is there any html being generated at all?  Have you used other fbml tags ok?

Comment: I got it working, not sure exactly what it was, but if I pinpoint the problem I will post the exact solution here, thanx again!

Answer (score 1):

Host your flash in a web page on a server. Then use the iframe on canvas to pull in that page thus your Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the swf in a html file and let the iFrame call for the html file. Worked like charm for me [here (under construction)](http://www.facebook.com/pages/TangoTango-Tangokurs-i-Oslo-Kurs-i-argentinsk-tango/244011302285113?sk=app_159130167497404). The original can be found [here](http://www.tangotango.no/resources/velkommen.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Perhaps provide a code example with the  link to an external site.   The external site might go away eventually, and then your helpful answer would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

With an iframe Canvas application, you shouldn't need to use `<fb:swf>`, and should instead rely on [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) or the like to embed it, as you would for a standard web page.

Answer (score 0):

this will never run because your application is iframe

this code will only run on FBML Canvas

any way if you use the html to render a flash will not run in IE but it will run with Firefox